# get rid of character from jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

jsFiddle seems to put a character in the fiddles that is invisible and causes erros when javascript is copy/pasted into another editor and run. I know the easy answer is simply not to copy/paste from that site. But supposing it's been done, and you must locate the character in your document: is there any tool online which can be used show invisible characters, and assist in their removal?

Comment: Erm, what? Can you show an example?

Comment: Also, where are you copying from?

Comment: @raina77ow Are you able to copy from jsfiddle without any problem? I never thought about it just being something unique to my computer :/

Comment: Sigh. Tell me, what's so hard in actually _describing_ the problem? What's the input? What's the output? Can you show this invisible character?

Comment: I've experienced the problem before but I don't know any way around it, I'd say use [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) instead...

Comment: For anyone out there wanting to reproduce the problem, just write something on jsfiddle and copy/paste all (Ctrl-A - Ctrl-V) in jsbin, and you'll see the extra character being added as a red dot.

Comment: @elclanrs: Thanks for actually explaining the problem here.

Comment: I can confirm this - it's when you are copying out of jsFiddle. How about that... You could just do a replace all after copying the text?

Comment: This character is U+200b (8203) called a "ZERO WIDTH SPACE". You can remove it by `.replace('\u200b','')`.

Comment: @raina77ow Nothing so hard about describing the problem. I've updated the question and I hope it's clearer. Sorry I made you sigh.

Comment: @PaulS. Could you submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The invisible character added by [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is **U+200B** (dec 8203) and called a "ZERO WIDTH SPACE". You can remove it by `.replace('\u200b','')`

Ironically, [**here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/djfdc/) for it.

Comment: Why the hell is it added anyway?

Comment: If it has a purpose it must be something to do with the as-you-type formatting indentation and colours, but I have no idea why they don't use something else that wouldn't break the code on copy.