# HTML generated with a double space tag after <body>

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

I use notepad++ and utf-8 encoding for writting php code. I faced an issue that my header is moved down. I founded that Firebug shows double space after `<body>`, so if I delete empty space, header sets to his place. But when I press 'Ctrl+U' to see the HTML code I see thats all is ok:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
       <div class="container">
      <img alt="" src="/../images/logo.png" class="active">
       </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

An important point if I choose Encode\Conver to ANSI issue dissapears. 
I cannot use ANSI as DB use UTF8 and records have Cyrillic chars.

Issue:

```
<body>

    <div id="header">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hex-editor to inspect the file. Somewhere between `<body>` and `<div...` there must be some "invisible" (e.g. '[whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)' or otherwise 'invisible') character. A list of hex-editors can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors).

The quickest solution though, for this example, is to simply save as ANSI/ASCII, reopen and save again as UTF-8. That should get rid of the invisible character or at least show some 'weird' character when reopening.

**edit**
I took a look at the issue you pasted in your question; I think the character got lost by copy/pasting because I don't see anything weird:
[image]

(Note that `0D` and `0A` are Carriage Return / Line Feeds, or "[normal (windows) newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)" and `20` is a normal space)

---

I just remembered: I did see this issue once or twice copying code from [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/); it's "formatter/syntax highlighter" seems (or seemed) to add some unwanted characters sometimes. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463458/get-rid-of-character-from-jsfiddle) for example.

Also, a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) sometimes is a source of trouble, but that wouldn't explain (AFAIK) why the space is between `<body>` and `<div...` because a BOM is the first few bytes in the file. If you're using multple PHP files with BOM's in them (using `include()`/`require()` etc.) to build the final output then one of these files might contain an unwanted(?) BOM.

Comment: Thank you I used XVI32 editor. I founded characters encode by FF BB BF before <!DOCTYPE html>. After deleting them I got what I want. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++, you must strictly use `UTF-8 without BOM` when working with PHP. `UTF-8` in notepad++ unfortunately means that a BOM will be prepended to every PHP source file.

Because PHP is encoding oblivious, it will just treat that as literal content to be echoed. This will cause all kinds of problems like `headers already sent` errors and your document going into quirks mode in some browsers.

It will be far easier to just use the `UTF-8 without BOM`-encoding than deleting the BOM created by `UTF-8` manually.

Comment: Thanks!
Also I found interesting article about it http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php